# div goes outside of <p> for unknown reason

Tags: html, css

I just noticed the divs inside the `<p>` go outside, so "do you want to receive..." is inside a `<p>`, and then after the divs there is an empty `<p></p>`, instead of it all being inside one `<p>`

Anyone sees a bug here?

```
<p class="subs1">
                Do you want to receive our emails and new collection previews? 
                <div style="" class="styledRadio first_radio">
                    <input type="radio" value="yes" name="user[collection_previews]" style="display: none;">
                </div>
                Yes 
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <div style=" width: 20px; height: 20px; cursor: pointer; background-position: 0px 0px;" class="styledRadio">
                    <input type="radio" value="no" name="user[collection_previews]" style="display: none;">
                </div>
                No
            </p>
```

The whole thing should be inside subs1 p but it isn't

Comment: Welcome to not following language specifications properly. This is not HTML's fault.

Comment: Allow me to introduce my little friend:  http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` tags cannot contain block level tags, they are considered invalid html, which accounts for the way your page is being rendered. It is breaking the block elements (`<div>` in this case) to be just that, block level elements.

Try changing the `<div>`s to a `<span>` instead.

The divs are 'block' type, which is the reason they are breaking out to their own lines. Changing them to spans (which are also inline) will allow you to wrap the item in a tag, while still keeping them on a single line.

Comment: the fast that <p> cant hold div is what really helped me, you shouldn't hav deleted that part. I chose this as the answer as it was the first reply. vote up for all, thanks

Comment: @OliveraKovacevic: You should accept the answer which helps you the most and/or is of the best quality, not which was "first". Stack Overflow is not a race.

Comment: It was the same as all the others, and first.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use block elements (`<div>`, `<form>`, `<p>`) etc. in `<p>` tags. Use `<div>` instead of `<p>`.

```
<div class="subs1">...</div>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html states that only [`phrasing content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is permitted. This means no block elements in these elements.

Answer (score 3):

[`p`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html) is for containing **p**aragraphs of *text*, not block elements like [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html)s.

Your browser is forced to re-organise the nodes because the way you've written them is *invalid HTML* and cannot be parsed into a valid and meaningful DOM tree.

Consider using a `div` for the outermost container, not a `p`.